# Laravel PHP Class doesn't display array data

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm currently following a tutorial for creating Laravel PHP Controllers, Views & Routes.  Here is my code:

**Authors2.php (Controller)**

```
class Authors2_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public function contact() {

        $view = View::make('authors2.index', array('name'=>'Andrew Perkins'))
            ->with('age', '28');
            $view->location = 'California';
            $view['specialty'] = 'PHP';
            return $view;
      }

}
```

**index.php (View)**

```
<h1>Authors2 Home Page </h1>

<?php echo $name; ?><br />
<?php echo $age; ?><br />
<?php echo $location; ?><br />
<?php echo $specialty; ?><br />
```

**routes.php (Route)**

```
Route::get('authors2', array('uses' =>'Authors2_Controller@contact'));
```

**Current Output**

```
Authors2 Home Page
```

**Desired Output**

```
Authors2 Home Page
Andrew Perkins
28
California
PHP
```

Please help me so that I can understand why the php data isn't being displayed properly under the header.  Thank you!

Comment: You are using four different ways of adding data to the view, including two that won't work (one of which treats the View object as an array). Why on earth?!

Comment: I've been following an online tutorial, so Laravel is still new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass data to the view like this:

```
$view = View::make('authors2.index', array('name'=>'Andrew Perkins'))
        ->with('age', '28')
        ->with('location', 'California')
        ->with('specialty', 'PHP);
```

Or like this:

```
return View::make('authors2.index', array(
    'name' => 'Andrew Perkins',
    'age' => 28,
    'location' => 'California',
    'specialty' => 'PHP'
));
```

Or like this:

```
$name = 'Andrew Perkins';
$age = 28;
$location = 'California';
$specialty = 'PHP';

return View::make('authors2.index', compact('name', 'age', 'location', 'specialty'));
```

Or, using the same variables as above:

```
return View::make('authors2.index')->with(compact('name', 'age', 'location', 'specialty'));
```

Or, you can do this too:

```
$view = View::make('authors2.index');
$name = 'Andrew Perkins';
$view->with(compact('name'));
$view->with('age', 28);
return $view;
```

Comment: I just tried using your code and its still not appearing.  Could it be due to the variables not being defined properly or them possibly being null?

Comment: @JeffP. Why would they be not defined or null? Your code is passing static strings to the view, not variables.

Comment: I actually figured out what was wrong.  The code was correct but my index.php was in the wrong file location.  Thank you for the help!